# Blue ticks in whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Would the blue ticks appear if a person does not have you in their whatsapp contact list?

Although you can see whether the message is delivered, you cannot see their name or status. So I wasn't sure what was the case with whatsapp's new 'read' feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control this thing in whatsapp as of now. Read status is enabled for everyone by default. The only thing you can control is 'last seen status'.

Comment: Looks like whatsapp is working on this problem.